# universal- and existential quantification in SQL

Tags: sql

given a relation

```
X | Y
-------
a | i
a | ii
b | ii
b | ii
```

how to query for

1. the set of all `X` for which there exists a `Y` of length 2 (should yield `{ a, b }`)
2. the set of all `X` for which all `Y` have length 2 (should yield `{ b }`)

Comment: Where does this terminology come from, "universal quantification" and "existential quantification"?

Comment: @estolua: Is this assignment or something?

Comment: If you want to get this result using SQL, have you tried to write a query?  If so, then you should include your attempts at getting the result.

Comment: @bluefeet yes I'm looking for a query. I can't imagine that the convoluted monstrosities of my trials so far would help anyone in answering this, I think the question is self-contained as it is.

Comment: @estolua problem is, as written you are asking users to write the code for you - that is typically frowned upon. We like to see some effort made that you've tried to write the queries and then explain why they don't work.

Comment: In addition, knowing where you are stuck will help us phrase the answer at your level of understanding, i.e. we will not explain stuff you already know, or omit stuff you need to know, but which you have yet to learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is fairly easy (note, in all the examples LENGTH_FUNCTION stands in for the product-specific length-of-string function in whatever SQL database you're using):

```
 SELECT DISTINCT X FROM RelationName WHERE LENGTH_FUNCTION(Y) = 2;
```

For the second one, there are a variety of ways to approach the problem.

```
 SELECT X FROM RelationName GROUP BY X 
    HAVING MIN(LENGTH_FUNCTION(Y)) = 2 AND MAX(LENGTH_FUNCTION(Y)) = 2
```

will aggregate all the X values and filter for those with only length of 2 while

```
 SELECT DISTINCT X FROM RelationName WHERE LENGTH_FUNCTION(Y) = 2
    AND X NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT X FROM RelationName WHERE LENGTH_FUNCTION(Y) <> 2)
```

uses the same filter as the first query, but additionally filters out any X values that exist elsewhere in the table with a non-length-2 Y value.  Finally

```
 SELECT DISTINCT X FROM RelationName RN1 WHERE LENGTH_FUNCTION(Y) = 2
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM RelationName WHERE X = RN1.X AND LENGTH_FUNCTION(Y) <> 2)
```

does the same filtering in a way you may find more expressive (but is likely to be less performant)